# OOM error when scrolling through gridview

Tags: java, android, gridview, scroll

I am working on an android application with a bunch of clickable gifs.

I created a gridview of gifs that is scrollable. The gifs are a gifmovieview from https://github.com/sbakhtiarov/gif-movie-view. The images keep loading into the memory each time I scroll, eventually causing a OOM error after scrolling up and down the list about 6-10 times.

How can I fix this? And possibly add smooth scrolling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't recycling images properly, so they weren't getting removed or reused from memory and kept getting added on top of each other.

I changed convertView!=null to convertView==null and put the inflate inside of it.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably keeping all the GIFs in memory.  Use an LRUCache to limit the number of GIFs in memory at a time.

Smooth scrolling issues are probably due to image decoding.  Move that to a separate thread, and show a placeholder image until its done.

Comment: I am not quite sure how to load them into the cache and back out. this is my getView method: http://pastebin.com/jXkjxs59